# What's the best approach to sharing device CLLocation between ViewControllers in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am building an app that uses `CoreLocation` to get the user's `CLLocation` in order to display location-based content throughout the app.

**What is the best approach to getting the device location**, saving it in one place so that is is accessible to multiple `ViewControllers` without the need of having have to invoke `CoreLocation` services in every `ViewController` where it's needed, instantiating a `CLLocationManager`, calling the `startUpdatingLocation()`, etc...

My initial thoughts were to use `UserDefaults` to save the location so that it is available throughout, **what is the best practice approach for this?**

thanks

Comment: Don’t misuse user defaults.

Comment: 1. make it a singleton. 2. give this singleton a property name `lastLocation` 3. update that property upon every callback you get from `didUpdateLocations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a singleton class to track location.

```
class CustomLocationManager:NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let shared = CustomLocationManager()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    private override init()
    {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    func startTracking()
    {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func stopTracking()
    {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Start tracking location when application launches

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    CustomLocationManager.shared.startTracking()
    return true
}
```

Then you can get the location from any view controller using this

```
guard let currentLocation = CustomLocationManager.shared.locationManager.location else {
return
```

}

Comment: @trungduc I haven't added any delegate method in this class. It is not mandatory.

Comment: My bad, you only need to add them if you use requestLocation

Comment: thanks Rajesh, I think this is enough to adapt to my specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

Check this Full working class to get location

-- I have used Geocoder here as I was required to get the Address With location Coordinates, modify class as per your requirement

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

    //MARK: Protocol
    //MARK:- Main Class
    /**
     This protocol is used to Update the result when Location is Fetched
     */
    protocol locationFetched : class
    {
        //mARK: Get Location Formatted
        /**
         This Class is used to perform all the required functions to get a new password
         - parameter locationFetched : Location String With Format
         - parameter lat : latitude of location Fetched
         - parameter lon : longitude of location Fetched
         */
        func locationAddressString(locationFetched:String, lat: CLLocationDegrees, lon: CLLocationDegrees)
    }

    //MARK: Location CLass
    /**
     This class is made to work with CLLocationManager
     */
    class GetLocation : NSObject
    {
        /// Completion Handler
        typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
        /// Shared instance of class
        @objc static let shared = GetLocation()
        /// Location Co-ordinated (2D)
        static var locationCoordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D!
        /// Location Manager - Used to get location
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        /// Object for loaction Protocol
        var locationDelegate : locationFetched?
        /// Current Location of User
        var currentLocation : CLLocation!
    }

    //MARK: Location CLass Extension
    /**
     This Extension contain all the required Function to get locationn from the Location Manager
     */
    extension GetLocation : CLLocationManagerDelegate
    {
        //MARK: Get Location
        /**
         This function is used to get the location
         */
        func getLocation()
        {
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }

        //MARK: Location manager Delegate
        /**
         Tells the delegate that new location data is available.
         - parameter manager : The location manager object that generated the update event.
         - parameter locations : An array of CLLocation objects containing the location data.
         */
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
        {
            guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            self.currentLocation = locationManager.location
            if self.currentLocation != nil
            {
                self.getAdress { (jsonDict, error) in
                    if error != nil
                    {
                        return
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let classObj = LocationOrganizer(jsonDict: jsonDict!)
                        self.locationDelegate?.locationAddressString(locationFetched: classObj.locationString, lat: self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, lon: self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                    }
                }
            }        
        }

        //MARK: Location manager Failure
        /**
         Tells the delegate that the location manager was unable to retrieve a location value.
         - parameter manager : The location manager object that generated the update event.
         - parameter error : The error object containing the reason the location or heading could not be retrieved.
         */
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        //MARK: Get Location Address
        /**
         completion Handler which retuen a Address or Value
         - parameter completion : Block which either Recieve a Dict or Error
         - parameter address : Dictionary containing all the description about current Location
         - parameter error : error While Getting location Details
         */
        func getAdress(completion: @escaping (_ address: JSONDictionary?, _ error: Error?) -> ())
        {
                let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
                geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.currentLocation) { placemarks, error in

                    if let e = error
                    {
                        completion(nil, e)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let placeArray = placemarks
                        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
                        placeMark = placeArray?[0]
                        guard let address = placeMark.addressDictionary as? JSONDictionary else {
                            return
                        }                    
                        completion(address, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    //MARK: Location Organizer - Formatter
    class LocationOrganizer
    {
        /// Location String - Contains the formatted location
        var locationString : String!

        //MARK: Initialise class
        /**
         initialise class and Return a Formatted Location string
         - parameter jsonDict : Dictionary with all the Address Details regardibg a Location
         */
        init(jsonDict: [String:Any]) {
            self.locationString = "\(jsonDict["Street"] ?? ""),\(jsonDict["SubLocality"] ?? ""),\(jsonDict["City"] ?? ""),\(jsonDict["State"] ?? "") \(jsonDict["ZIP"] ?? ""), \(jsonDict["Country"] ?? "")"
        }
    }

    // MARK: Check Location service is On or Off
    /**
     function check did user allowed to make use of location to app and do GPS is Enabled ?
     - parameter manager : Location Manager class Instance
     - parameter status : Status of App to get Location Allowed or not ?
     */
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .restricted:
            print("Location access was restricted.")
        case .denied:
                  print("User denied access to location.")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Location status not determined.")
        case .authorizedAlways: fallthrough
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Location status is OK.")
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        GetLocation.shared.locationDelegate = self
        GetLocation.shared.getLocation()
    }

//MARK:- Location Manager class Delegate
extension AddingPropertyVC : locationFetched
{
    func locationAddressString(locationFetched: String, lat: CLLocationDegrees, lon: CLLocationDegrees) {
        self.meanValuesArray[1] = locationFetched
        self.currentLat = lat
        self.currentLon = lon
        self.submitBool = true
        self.addPropertyTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I must say that I am fairly new to swift/coding so I need to get my head around your suggestion, in particular removing the code that doesnt apply to my requirements.